# Label Html helper is show up as string literal <label...> contents instead of being rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Q:  How do I get this to render as a ?  It' showing up as string literal text instead of being renderd into an actual  element.

```
public static class HtmlExtensions 
{
    public static string LabelX(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string target, string text, string _class)
    {
        return (String.Format( "<label class='{2}' for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text, _class);              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an MvcString not a regular string.